# What does this statement signify?

Tags: special-relativity

*With ref. to "Introduction to Special Relativity by Robert Resnick (1968)"*

In the book, while explaining the Michelson Morley experiment there's a statement on pg. 21 that says

> "If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are very nearly (but not quite) at right angles, we shall observe a fringe system in the telescope..."

$M_1$ and $M_2$ are the mirrors.

Now, as per my understanding of the Math that follows, I see no point where the mirrors $M_1$ and $M_2$ doesn't have to be exactly perpendicular...

Is there any physical reason behind it that I am not aware of?

Edit: Image with more details as an excerpt from the book cited.

[image]

This is the interferometer:
[image]

Comment: We'll need more than this.  We have no idea what $M_1$ and $M_2$ are, what is the geometry of the device producing fringes, and so on.  Please provide a complete description.

Comment: Information added.

Comment: Aha.  The mirrors could be made intentionally off-perpendicular in order to create fringes.  It's also very difficult in practice to make them exactly perpendicular.  In fact it would be quite a task to make them perpendicular enough to see the fringes at all.

Comment: @garyp Regarding the first point, I understand that even if the mirrors are perpendicular it should form fringes in the presence of *ether* and the experiment was to do the same. So, I guess that makes the second point true in this case, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the mirrors were exactly perpendicular, there would be no fringes. This is because there would be no change in the optical distance for different locations on the mirror.

Answer (score 0):

If the mirrors were **exactly** perpendicular since the mirror $M$ is inclined $45^\circ$ degrees ,the beams would be parallel and there will be no interference in the interferometer and therefore no fringes.

Note that the original experiment used a series of reflections to make the "light path as long as possible " - you can see the plan view of it in the [wikipedia of the experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment#/media/File:On_the_Relative_Motion_of_the_Earth_and_the_Luminiferous_Ether_-_Fig_4.png) ( and also in the book too).